# Multiply variables - One array

Tags: php, forms, variables, post, submit

On my website, I have a form, with 3 checkboxes. Each checkboxes has a different value.

Example:

```
$upgrade = inputFilter($_POST['upgrade']); //Has the value of "1"
$masterU = inputFilter($_POST['masteru']); //Has the value of "2"
$extended = inputFilter($_POST['extended ']); //Has the value of "3"
```

I have to insert all of the 3 variables, into ONE cell in my database, and it should look like this: 1,2,3

How can this be obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$value = sprintf("%s,%s,%s", $upgrade, $masterU, $extended);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use implode to build a comma separated list.

```
$array = array($upgrade, $masterU, $extended);
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
```